# Query to mark if a value falls between a set of values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables. And I want to check if a value from one, falls between any two numbers in the other table. For example the tables are:

```
table_a:
+--------+-------+---------------------+
|  name  | count |        time         |
+--------+-------+---------------------+
| table1 | 10    | 2019-05-03 10:30:00 |
| table1 | 20    | 2019-05-03 11:30:00 |
| table1 | 30    | 2019-05-03 12:30:00 |
| table1 | 40    | 2019-05-03 13:30:00 |
| table1 | 50    | 2019-05-03 14:30:00 |
+--------+-------+---------------------+

table_b:
+--------+-------+
|  name  | count |
+--------+-------+
| table1 | 35    |
+--------+-------+
```

From this I want to get the closest value above and below the number in table_b that exists in table_a, and then show this as a "match" and then also display the times of the closest value above and below this number. So the results should look something similar to:

```
Result:
+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  name  |    count     |     time_before     |     time_after      |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| table1 | Counts Match | 2019-05-03 12:30:00 | 2019-05-03 13:30:00 |
+--------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

If this doesn't match, then it will show this in the results as not matching and the times will just be blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by generating a table of `before` and `after` values for `count` and `time` in `table_a`, and then `JOIN`ing that to `table_b` such that `table_b.count` is between `count_before` and `count_after`:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       a.count_before || ',' || a.count_after  AS count,
       a.time_before,
       a.time_after
FROM (SELECT name,
             lag(count) over (order by time) AS count_before,
             count AS count_after,
             lag(time) over (order by time) AS time_before,
             time AS time_after
      FROM table_a) a
JOIN table_b b ON b.count BETWEEN a.count_before AND a.count_after
```

Output:

```
name    count   time_before                 time_after
table1  30,40   2019-05-03T12:30:00.000Z    2019-05-03T13:30:00.000Z
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51BNRRpHkTz7eghj24zyfZ/1)

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can generate the list of start/end counts (and timestamps) using a window function, then join that to the second table:

```
with ranges as ( 
  select name, 
         "time" as time_start,
         "count" as count_start, 
         lead("count") over w as count_end, 
         lead("time") over w as time_end
  from table_a
  window w as (partition by name order by "time")
)
select t2.name, t2."count", r.count_start, r.count_end, r.time_start, r.time_end
from table_b t2 
  join ranges r on r.name = t2.name and t2."count" between r.count_start and r.count_end;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/MBYZYU33789

Answer (score 1):

One method is a lateral join:

```
select b.*, a.lower, a.upper
from table_b b cross join lateral
     (select max(lower) as lower, max(upper) as upper
      from ((select a.time as lower, null as upper
             from table_a a
             where a.value <= b.value
             order by b.time desc
             fetch first 1 row only
            ) union all
            (select null as lower, a.time as upper
             from table_a a
             where a.value >= b.value
             order by b.time asc
             fetch first 1 row only
            )
           ) a
      ) a
```